# Getting ksh: NF: not found on executing ssh command

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ssh, ksh

My below command throwing error like : **ksh: NF:  not found.**

```
sshpass -p 'pass' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user awk -v columnCount=64 -F '\\|' 'NF && NR > 1  && NR < 12058  && NF != columnCount+1 {exit 1}' /var/prod/scms/landing/store_data_20201202010002.dat && echo 'success' || echo 'failed'
```

Can anyone please help me here, what I have done wrong.

Comment: What actually is your field delimter here?

Comment: @michjnich | symbol

Comment: Not sure you need the double escape there in that case. COuld be that's throwing something off ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original code is:

```
sshpass -p 'pass' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user awk -v columnCount=64 -F '\\|' 'NF && NR > 1  && NR < 12058  && NF != columnCount+1 {exit 1}' /var/prod/scms/landing/store_data_20201202010002.dat && echo 'success' || echo 'failed'
```

Relevant part is: `ssh user awk -F '\\|' 'NF && NR > 1'`

1. The local shell strips the single-quotes (while parsing the commandline) and so ssh never sees them.
2. ssh concatenates its arguments into a single string and passes it to the remote shell.
3. The remote shell receives from ssh: `awk -F \\| NF && NR > 1`
4. This is a pipeline (`|`) followed by a control command (`&&`)
5. Therefore the remote shell tries to run `awk` and `NF` in parallel, with `awk` stdout connected to `NF` stdin.
6. No program called `NF` is found so the remote shell throws the error seen.
7. Because the pipeline fails, the command after the `&&` is not executed and so the redirection (`> 1`) does not happen and no attempt is made to run a command `NR`